# LESS CSS nesting classes

Tags: css, nested, less

I'm using LESS to improve my CSS and am trying to nest a class within a class. There's a fairly complicated hierarchy but for some reason my nesting doesn't work.
I have this:

```
.g {
    float: left;
    color: #323a13;
    .border(1px,#afc945);
    .gradient(#afc945, #c8da64);
    .common;
    span {
        .my-span;
        .border-dashed(1px,rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
    }
    .posted {
         .my-posted;
         span {
            border: none;
         }
    }
}
```

I can't get the `.g.posted` to work. it just shows the `.g` bit.
If i do this it's fine:

```
.g {
    float: left;
    color: #323a13;
    .border(1px,#afc945);
    .gradient(#afc945, #c8da64);
    .common;
    span {
        .my-span;
        .border-dashed(1px,rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
    }
}

.g.posted {
         .my-posted;
         span {
            border: none;
         }
    }
```

I'd like to nest the `.posted` in `.g` though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

The `&` character has the function of a `this` keyword, actually (a thing I did not know at the moment of writing the answer). It is possible to write:

```
.class1 {
    &.class2 {}
}
```

and the CSS that will be generated will look like this:

```
.class1.class2 {}
```

For the record, @grobitto was the first to post this piece of information.

---

**[ORIGINAL ANSWER]**

LESS doesn't work this way.

`.class1.class2 {}` - defines two classes on the same DOM node, but

```
.class1 {
    .class2 {}
}
```

defines nested nodes. `.class2` will only be applied if it is a child of a node with the class `class1`.

I've been confused with this too and my conclusion is that LESS needs a `this` keyword :).

Comment: `sass` has that functionality built in with the & operator.

Comment: LESS is still awesome, especially the PHP LESS preprocessor, with its modified, more flexible syntax. But until there's some sort of commonly accepted syntax, such problems will arise from time to time. In my view, this one is LESS' only drawback.

Comment: @newbie_86 You cannot mix sass and native css syntax. So migrating to Sass requires a complete re-write of your styles, while in less you can already compile your existing styles and start re-writing them piece by piece.

Comment: I was curious why second answer have more ups than this one, despite it's same and have latter date. Then i saw last sentence and upped both answers

Comment: @topless what do you mean by "You cannot mix sass and native css syntax" I've been doing it for years. Works great for me.

Comment: @topless: Completely untrue. For example, you can take a .css file, change the extension to .scss, make no other changes and run it through SASS. It will work perfectly.

Comment: I'd rejig this answer to have the edit on top, I almost missed it and left thinking "this is impossible"

Comment: I think it's probably time to rewrite this answer to combine the original answer and the edit, and so it doesn't start with the comment (especially as it is this part that is now shown on google).

Answer (score 121):

```
.g {
    &.posted {
    }
}
```

you should add "&" before .posted

Answer (score 2):

If the ampersand is located right next to the child element in nesting, it is compiled into a double class selector.  If there is space between & and selector it will be compiled into child selector. Read more about nesting in Less [here](https://kolosek.com/nesting-in-less-and-sass).