# Apply style to child elements with LESS

Tags: css, less

This works:

```
.layoutList {
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
.layoutList > .entityCard.hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Why doesn't this work the same as the above code?  What is the appropriate way to "cascade" this in LESS so that everything is under the main .layoutList {} section?

```
.layoutList {
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
    .entityCard.hover {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you meant to write `:hover` rather than `.hover`, or is that the actual class name?

Comment: Yeah, that's an actual class name.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah ok just wondering, just didn't know if that was important or not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have for your LESS should work. It compiles to this CSS:

```
.layoutList {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
.layoutList .entityCard.hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

***The only thing missing is if you want the child combinator*** as your example shows, then you need to tweak your LESS to this (where the `>` was added):

```
.layoutList {
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
    > .entityCard.hover {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
}
```

Which will then output this:

```
.layoutList {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
.layoutList > .entityCard.hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: Crap my first test was apparently cached.  Still playing with it, but I don't think this worked :(

Comment: If it didn't work, then I'd have to say you had a seriously faulty LESS compiler you are using. It works clear back to version LESS 1.1 at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/)

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, I had typed something wrong or something.  It is working.

Comment: This question was very helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117133/less-css-nesting-classes

Comment: might be fair to point out that in your LESS you shouldn't leave a space between `>` and `.` in this case, as it shouldn't work with the space.

Comment: @VictorRamos: I do not see the point of your comment. Every LESS compiler I have used has no issue with a space between the direct child selector  (`>`) and the `.` beginning a class name.