# How to nest Less class to inherit parent styles?

Tags: css, less

**LESS code:**

```
.btn-default:hover {
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
    background-clip: content-box;

    .btn-default:focus {
        outline: 2px solid #047a9c;
    }
}
```

What i want to do here is that `btn-default:focus` should have background color of hover state but only focus state should have the outline. so the output CSS should be:

```
 .btn-default:hover {
     background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
     background-clip: content-box;
 }

 .btn-default:focus {
     background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
     background-clip: content-box;
     outline: 2px solid #047a9c;
 }
```

I am bit lost at the LESS nesting part, is this something possible with less? So that i don't have to duplicate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to nest pseudo-classes only into main selector. In this case `.btn-default`.

This is how it should look:

```
.btn-default {
  /* some code here */

  &:hover, &:focus {
    background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
    background-clip: content-box;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #047a9c;
  }
}
```

The `&` character has the function of a "this" keyword

**From your original question:**

```
.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
  background-clip: content-box;

  .btn-default:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #047a9c;
  }
}
```

Less doesn't work this way. Try to pronounce your code. Your code would be like this in CSS:

```
.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.65);
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.btn-default:hover.btn-default:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #047a9c;
}
```

You have to nest pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements into main selector (`.btn-default`)

If you want more selectors, pseudo-elements or pseudo-classes to have same properties, you should use `,`, not to nest one inside another.

---

Here are some helpful links:

[Less to CSS compiler](https://www.cssportal.com/less-to-css/)

[LESS CSS nesting classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117133/less-css-nesting-classes)

[Pseudo classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)