# How should the HTML structure in the example correspond to less

Tags: html, css, less

This is my HTML code.

```html
<div class="app-menu-layout">
  <main class="app-menu-layout-main">
    <div class="app-menu-layout-main-container">Hello World</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Here's what I did, but he was wrong

```
.app-menu-layout {
  &>&-main {
    &>&-container{
      color:red
    }
  }
}


// Compiled CSS
.app-menu-layout>.app-menu-layout-main>.app-menu-layout>.app-menu-layout-main-container {
  color: red;
}
```

expected results:

```css
.app-menu-layout>.app-menu-layout-main>.app-menu-layout-main-container {
  color: red;
}
```

How should I write the nested structure of less?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to select all the parents, just select `.app-menu-layout-main-container`

Answer (score 0):

Just write the correct class names. e.g

```
.app-menu-layout {
   &.app-menu-layout-main {
      &.app-menu-layout-main-container{
        color:red;
       }
    }
 }
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117133/less-css-nesting-classes) to nested LESS.